# How do I deny the condition that is in if below

Tags: r

How do I deny the condition that is in if below?

```
if(any(PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk, na.rm = TRUE)){
....
}
```

In the condition above I am considering if it has `PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk`. But if you want to deny it, for example, if you don't have `PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk`, what would it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on whether you want the entire condition to be `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You probably want `!any`. Make a small example:

```
a <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
b <- c(3, 4, 3, 4)

cbind(a, b)
#      a b
# [1,] 1 3
# [2,] 1 4
# [3,] 2 3
# [4,] 2 4

a == 1 & b == 3
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
any(a == 1 & b == 3)
# [1] TRUE
!any(a == 1 & b == 3)
# [1] FALSE

a == 3 & b == 5
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
any(a == 1 & b == 5)
# [1] FALSE
!any(a == 1 & b == 5)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can deny with **!** symbol

```
if(!(2 > 1)) {...}
```

I don't know if it is possible to do it in R as the same way